# mySql INNER JOIN Confusion

Tags: php, mysqli

I have been racking my brains for ages trying to figure this out but just can't seem to get my head round it.  There is plenty of information out there but I have been unable to get it right.
I understand that using the following method is not good:

WHERE id IN (SELECT.....

I am trying to optimize the query below as I have many of this type in one script and it is making the page dreadfully slow:

```
$res = mysqli_query($DB, 'SELECT * FROM nde WHERE id IN (SELECT relto FROM ft_n_rel WHERE rel_fr = '.$DB->real_escape_string($rid).' AND rel_ty = '.$DB->real_escape_string($FA).') LIMIT 1');
```

Trying to do that query optimizes with INNER JOIN is completely baffling me.

Can anyone help?

Regards

Comment: check your indexes, it may cause this problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sub-selects and `in array` clauses are always very slow.

Try:

```
SELECT n.* 
FROM nde n
    INNER JOIN ft_n_rel f ON n.id = f.relto
WHERE f.rel_fr = '.$DB->real_escape_string($rid).' 
    AND f.rel_ty = '.$DB->real_escape_string($FA).'
LIMIT 1
```

@daremachine has a good point as well, run your select with `EXPLAIN` or `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` to check if indexes exist and are properly used.

**Update**
To check the page with explain prefix you query as follows:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT n.* 
FROM nde n
    INNER JOIN ft_n_rel f ON n.id = f.relto
WHERE f.rel_fr = '.$DB->real_escape_string($rid).' 
    AND f.rel_ty = '.$DB->real_escape_string($FA).'
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: this is probably the best your going to get.  The 'Limit 1' was needed in your sub-query because you needed to return only one result, doesn't function the same here so it may not be needed.  That said I don't know the intentions of the query so maybe you do want a single result, if so you may want to order the results of the query so you know what result you will be returning.

Comment: Actually the `LIMIT 1` is not part of the sub-query (including in the original query).

Comment: Sorry, I get Unknown Table n.  Also, how to I add the EXPLAIN to the query? Please excuse my lack of knowledge. Thank you all for your continued help.

Comment: `n` in the example above is an `alias` you need to make sure the alias is correctly specified.

Comment: Marc, thank you very much for your help on that. Much appreciated buddy.

Comment: Marc, I found the query that was causing the most damage but I am finding this one complex to convert to what you showed me:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31299352/optimize-php-mysqli-query-correctly